# Redux async issue - Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Adding async redux functionality to my code. Having an issue with fetching my `db.json` on the front-end. Getting

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

**contactOperations.js**

```js
import phoneActions from "./phoneActions";
import axios from "axios";

const addContact = (name, number) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(phoneActions.addContactRequest());

  axios
    .post("http://localhost:2000/contacts", { name, number })
    .then((response) => dispatch(phoneActions.addContactSuccess(response.data)))
    .catch((error) => dispatch(phoneActions.addContactError(error)));
};

export default { addContact };
```

**phoneActions.js**

```js
import { createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const addContactRequest = createAction("contacts/request");
const addContactSuccess = createAction("contacts/success");
const addContactError = createAction("contacts/error");


const removePhone = createAction("contact/remove");

const filterPhone = createAction("contact/filter");

export default {
  addContactRequest,
  addContactSuccess,
  addContactError,
  addPhone,
  removePhone,
  filterPhone,
};
```

**phoneReducer.js**

```js
import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import phoneActions from "./phoneActions";

const onAddContact = (state, action) => {
   const contactCheck = state.some(
    contact => contact.name === action.payload.name
  );
  if (contactCheck) {
    alert("exisits");
  } else {
    return [...state, action.payload]
  }
};

const onRemoveContact = (state, action) =>
  state.filter(contacts => contacts.id !== action.payload);

const contacts = createReducer([], {
  [phoneActions.addContactSuccess]: onAddContact,
  [phoneActions.removePhone]: onRemoveContact
});

const filter = createReducer("", {
  [phoneActions.filterPhone]: (state, action) => action.payload
});

export default { contacts, filter };
```

When consoling action, it shows undefined :

[image]

Comment: try with [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/) lib

Comment: Are you sure that response.data is defined?

Comment: Since you are using Redux Toolkit, you should use `createAsyncThunk` to define an asynchronous action in place of `addContact`. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Comment: @Benjamin - yes, reponse.data is defined : https://prnt.sc/rueb14 and https://prnt.sc/rueb7l

Comment: jus fixed this error by making this update: https://prnt.sc/ruecio

Comment: @AlexB, thats literally the same code. You just destructured data from the response object...